# Add a point to expand polygon without appending it in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I'm building a polygon in Google Maps through markers that can be dragged to reshape it. So, when there are 3 markers, the polygon is drawn, and further markers are appended in the shape, expanding it. That's fine when the user just want to follow a simple clockwise/counterclockwise pattern, but when he wants to expand the polygon through one of its edges, instead it will append the marker, twisting itself.

[image: Normal appending marker]

Here in this example, if we add markers 1, 2 and 3, it will be drawn a simple triangle. But if marker 4 is added, the polygon just twists itself.

Instead, I want when 4 is added, it's inserted between markers 1 and 2, like this image:

[image: Wanted appending marker]

Basically, in the polygon's vertex array, instead of:

```
[
    //marker 1 position,
    //marker 2 position,
    //marker 3 position,
    //current marker 4 position
]
```

I want to have:

```
[
    //marker 1 position,
    //desired marker 4 position
    //marker 2 position,
    //marker 3 position
]
```

So the polygon will expand instead of twist itself.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or I just will have to tell the user to build his polygon clock/counterclockwise?

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't use the drawing-library?

Comment: [similar question: How to sort points in a Google maps polygon so that lines do not cross?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374708/how-to-sort-points-in-a-google-maps-polygon-so-that-lines-do-not-cross)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort latitude and longitude coordinates into clockwise ordered quadrilateral](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855189/sort-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-into-clockwise-ordered-quadrilateral)

Comment: @Dr.Molle well, didn't know that library until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it via finding the nearest edge and inserting it after the first vertex and before the second one of this edge. I used the algorithm from here to use it in javascript:

[Shortest distance between a point and a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)

Answer (score 6):

General solution (find a center point, sort the points in order of heading from that point, using geometry library computeHeading method).

given an array gmarkers containing google.maps.Marker objects representing the vertices of the polygon:

```
function sortPoints2Polygon() {
      if (polyline) polyline.setMap(null);
      points = [];
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
      for (var i=0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        points.push(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
    bounds.extend(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
      }
      var center = bounds.getCenter();
      var bearing = [];
      for (var i=0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i].bearing = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(center,points[i]);
      }
      points.sort(bearingsort);
      polyline = new google.maps.Polygon({
        map: map,
        paths:points, 
        fillColor:"#FF0000",
        strokeWidth:2, 
        fillOpacity:0.5, 
        strokeColor:"#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity:0.5
      });
}

function bearingsort(a,b) {
  return (a.bearing - b.bearing);
}
```

[working example (starts with 3 random points)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_sortPoints2Polygon.html)