# Draw google maps polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon

How I can draw polygons on google maps using javascript.

I'm interested to draw some thing like the below polygons on the picture, and avoid drawing the above polygons.

My idea is to draw only polygons with lines uncrossed, how i can control that?

[image: polygons]

Comment: please add some code to show us what you've tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a point to expand polygon without appending it in Google Maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047932/add-a-point-to-expand-polygon-without-appending-it-in-google-maps/)